# Matrix singularity leads to irreversibility

Tags: python, pytorch

When I use torch, I process the mean and cov of a batch of data.When I need to invert cov later, a singular matrix error occurs.

```
The diagonal element 3 is zero, the inversion could not be completed because the input matrix is singular.
```

I tried adding a perturbation amount to prevent irreversibility, but it still didn't work.I don't know how to deal with it.

```
cov_eps = torch.eye(mean.shape[1]) * (1e-12)

inv_cov = torch.linalg.inv(cov[k] + cov_eps)
```

Comment: What happens for larger `eps=1e-6`?

Comment: How was `cov[k]` computed? Also, couldn't this example be simplified to without the `k`?

Comment: I tried `eps=1e-10` but it still occurs, I'm trying to increase it step by step.

Comment: cov is an n*k-dimensional matrix, and [k] indicates its position in the matrix, which is actually irrelevant to k.
The calculation of cov is a bit complicated.